# Python 3: Creating files in relative directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory, operating-system

I want to create a new directory in the same folder as my Python project and want to create a new text file in that place.

How can I do this **without** using the absolute directory name?

Comment: I am pretty sure the functions you are using (which we can just guess as you don't show any) can take relative paths..

Comment: Please post the code you're using.  It should be a simple matter of using the relative path name in the creation and use commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have the directory of the python project relative to where the script was called from and you also have either the absolute directory you want to create the folder in or it's location relative to where you called the script from, see the following:

```
import os

rel_directory=os.path.relpath(target_directory,base_directory)
```

Here the second line returns the relative path from base_directory to target_directory.

If you want the current working directory you could do something like `os.path.relpath('.','/')` or `os.path.realpath('.')` or `os.getcwd()`. Those are all the same if you don't change the current working directory after the start of the script.

From there you can just add the appropriate relative directory in front of the part to open the file.

```
f=open(rel_directory+'/'+filename,'a')
f.write("some stuff I'm adding to the file")
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is a very helpful line of code.